# Where can I buy 3/4" fine thread drywall screws in Canada?

Tags: drywall, basement, sound-proofing

I live in Canada, and it's hard to buy stuff here :)

Describing my use case a bit here, for my soundproofing in the basement ceiling I'm constructing rockwool + sonopan + resilient channel + 5/8" drywall.

This is actually the recommended construction per sonopan, to minimize holes cut for pot lights. Resilient channel would give some room between sonopan and drywall to house pot light connectors.

So since resilient channel is already part of the assembly, I would like to make the best use out of it. Meaning I don't want to puncture and connect sonopan and drywall. 1 1/4" screws will do exactly that.

Rough sketch to illustrate
[image]

I've searched all over internet for 3/4" fine thread drywall screws so that I refrain from screwing all the way in to sonopan. But it's so hard to find them in Canada! Either I have to pay crazy shipping or it's not available to ship.

Anyone know where I can get 3/4" drywall screws in Vancouver, Canada?

Comment: The thread is suppose to bite into the supporting surface(wood 2x4s).  What you probably want is drywall screws with a smooth shank.  Half thread, half shank.

Comment: I'm failing to see how the drywall will successfully attach to anything with such short screws. However if that's what you need, Lowes stocks particle board screws in that length, which are quite a lot like drywall screws. You can also order actual drywall screws that length via Grainger but they are currently backordered.

Comment: Agreed with above, 3/4” isn’t going to hold the drywall in place securely. More generally if you are in Vancouver and need specialized construction materials of any kind that isn’t at Big Orange or Big Blue, you should check out the local independent building stores: Windsor Plywood, Irly Building Centres, Kerrisdale Lumber. I don’t endorse them but they’re the most popular local non-chain shops.

Comment: Thanks. With resilient channel the screws are supposed to only attach to the channel itself and not the framing member the channel is attached to. The idea is to decouple the drywall from the framing members.
I'll check out local building stores.

Comment: Check out Brafasco on Terminal Avenue.

Answer (score 2):

Found them on Grainger. Apparently they're not very Google friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

Big box hardware stores cover every possible category **badly**.

A) Get out the yellow pages and look under fasteners, go there during business hours.

or

B) Go to a place that sells only drywall supplies during trades hours.
As a walk-in customer they may charge you double trade rates, it will still be cheaper.